# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
const UNCOMPLETED_LIST_BOOK_ID = "books";

function addBook() {
    const uncompletedBOOKList = document.getElementById(UNCOMPLETED_LIST_BOOK_ID );

    const titleBook = document.querySelector("#inputBookTitle").value;
    const authorBook = document.querySelector("#inputBookAuthor").value;
    const yearBook = document.querySelector("#inputBookYear").value;
    const isComplete = document.querySelector("#inputBookIsComplete").checked
    const idBook = +new Date
    console.log("title: " + titleBook);
    console.log("author: " + authorBook);
    console.log("year: " + yearBook);
    console.log("isComplete: " + isComplete);
    console.log("ID: " + idBook);

    const book = makeBook(titleBook, authorBook, yearBook);
    uncompletedBOOKList.append(book);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    const submitForm = document.getElementById("inputBook");

    submitForm.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        addBook();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain your problem with details please ?

Comment: Do you actually have an element with the id of `books`? Give us a little more detail

Comment: Well `document.getElementById(UNCOMPLETED_LIST_BOOK_ID );` returns `null` as the error says

Comment: Do you have an html example? Also, you should use ```appendChild``` instead of 
 ```append```

Comment: There is no element with ID `books` - can you share your HTML too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the same JS script on multiple HTML pages, the element you're querying for might not exist on the other pages?

You could check:

```
if (!!uncompletedBOOKList) {
   # What you would like to do
}
```